# Separar item respectivo de um array JSON

Tags: php, json

tudo bem? Eu gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar o valor respectivo em "href" neste foreach:

```
<?php 
$getJson = file_get_contents('file.json');
$listMenuJson = json_decode($getJson, true);

foreach ($listMenuJson as $valor) {
$a_tag = implode('<a>', explode(',', ','.$valor['categorias_alt']));

echo '<div class="btn-group">';
    echo '<div class="dropdown">';
        echo '<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">'.$valor['titulo'];
        echo '<span class="caret"></span></button>';
        echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
            echo '<li>';
                echo '<a href="'.$valor['codigo'].'">'.$valor['categorias'].'</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

O meu JSON está assim:

```
[
{
    "codigo":"termos",
    "titulo":"Termos Gerais",
    "categorias_alt":"Ephélian, Lentzh, Gourphour",
    "categorias":"ephelian, lentzh, gourphour"
},
{
    "codigo":"contos",
    "titulo":"Contos & Lendas",
    "categorias_alt":"Ephélian, Lentzh, Gourphour",
    "categorias":"ephelian, lentzh, gourphour"
},
{
    "codigo":"cabinet",
    "titulo":"Cabinet Escarlate",
    "categorias_alt":"Ephélian, Lentzh, Gourphour",
    "categorias":"ephelian, lentzh, gourphour"
}
]
```

No caso, esta parte aqui:

```
echo '<a href="'.$valor['codigo'].'">'.$valor['categorias'].'</a>';
```

O sistema funciona, mas ao invés de retornar, por exemplo:

```
<a href="ephelian">Ephélian</a>
<a href="lentzh">Lentzh</a>
<a href="gourphour">Gourphour</a>
```

Ele retorna isso:

```
<a href="ephelian,lentzh,gourphour">Ephélian</a>
<a href="ephelian,lentzh,gourphour">Lentzh</a>
<a href="ephelian,lentzh,gourphour">Gourphour</a>
```

Eu creio que eu esteja deixando passar alguma coisa que não estou concatenando nesta linha:

```
$a_tag = implode('<a>', explode(',', ','.$valor['categorias_alt']));
```

Quem puder dar uma luz, agradeço ^_^

Comment: Por que minha pergunta foi negativada? Estava editando a mesma. Acabei por enviar sem querer antes de terminar a edição

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz assim que funcionará:

```
$getJson = file_get_contents('file.json');
$listMenuJson = json_decode($getJson, true);

foreach ($listMenuJson as $valor) {
$categorias_alt = explode(',', $valor['categorias_alt']);
$categorias = explode(',', $valor['categorias']);

echo '<div class="btn-group">';
    echo '<div class="dropdown">';
        echo '<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">'.$valor['titulo'];
        echo '<span class="caret"></span></button>';
        echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
            for($x = 0; $x < count($categorias_alt); $x++){
                echo '<li>';
                    echo '<a href="'.$categorias[$x].'">'.$categorias_alt[$x].'</a>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}
```

Um dos erros é querer implodir um link `<a>` retirando uma vírgula de cada elemento. Isso não dá certo porque a tag `<a>` não será fechada.

Esse implode junto com o explode retorna algo parecido com isso: `Ephélian Lentzh Gourphour`

```
$a_tag = implode('<a>', explode(',', ','.$valor['categorias_alt']));
```

Seu código ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
<a>Ephélian <a>Lentzh <a>Gourphour // links que nunca se fecham
```

Comment: Putz, cara. Que manca a minha huahuuah
E bacana esta fórmula com for. Apesar de mexer com PHP há um bom tempo, ainda negligencio alguns estudos. Vou estudar mais sobre loppings pra ver se não preciso vir aqui da próxima vez huahuahu

Muito obrigado!

Comment: @AlexLupóz kkk.. sem problema.

Comment: ;) opa. Boa sorte!